# Can I use gitlab-rails to create a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed gitlab with the omnibus package on a Ubuntu-based machine, on which I'm trying to develop a rails app as well. Since gitlab installs ruby and the rails framework for itself, could I be able to use it to create new rails applications? When I run `gitlab-rails new app_name` under my home directory I get an error message that reads:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-rails error: could not load /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc
Either you are not allowed to read the file, or it does not exist yet.
You can generate it with: sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

And when I run `sudo gitlab-rails new app_name` I get:

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the director of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help
```

I've tried to run this under newly created, empty directories, but keep getting the same message. I assume `gitlab-rails` tries to create the new app under the gitlab project directory for some reason?

Comment: I don't think this even makes sense to do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn't the purpose of the gitlab-rails command and isn't a supported functionality. It'd be a much better idea to create a new Rails app by just using the Rails gem itself.